# How can I make my function work with my if statement that changes my array

Tags: php

In the script below I have an array. My array stores all the links, titles and descriptions from a web page. But I want to make sure that if there is no description, it will use the first 20 characters of a p tag using a function which works. Only problem is I have the jigsaw pieces and just can't seem to put them together, So I want my if statement to show that if the description is empty to use the function getWord instead of `getMetas()`.

```
function getMetas($link) {
  $str1 = file_get_contents($link);    
  if (strlen($str1)>0) {
    preg_match_all( '/<meta.*?name=("|\')description("|\').*?content=("|\')(.*?)("|\')/i', $str1, $description);
    if (count($description) > 1) {
      return $description[4];   
    }
  }
}
```

Then my function goes here (`get_custom_excert`), but there is no need to see that as I know that works.

```
function getWord() {
  $html = file_get_contents($link);    
  preg_match('%(<p[^>]*>.*?</p>)%i', $html, $re);
  $res = get_custom_excerpt($re[1]);
}

$outputs = array();

foreach ($links as $thisLink) {
  $output[] = array("link" => $thisLink, "title" => Titles($thisLink), "description" => getMetas($thisLink));

  if ($output['description'] == null) {
  $output['description'] = getWord($res);
  }

  $outputs[] = $output;
}

print_r($output);
```

Comment: sorry about that, forgot to change my title and have done now :)

Comment: regexes? html? the goggles...they do nothing!

Answer (score 0):

How is this?

```
foreach ($links as $thisLink) {
  $output = array("link" => $thisLink, "title" => Titles($thisLink), "description" => getMetas($thisLink));

  if ($output['description'] == null) {
  $output['description'] = getWord($res);
  }

  $outputs[] = $output;
}
```

Comment: I was mistaken. Your error was the $output[] which should be $output.

Answer (score 0):

Is this waht you want?

```
function getMetas($link) {
  $str1 = file_get_contents($link);    
  if (strlen($str1)>0) {
    preg_match_all( '/<meta.*?name=("|\')description("|\').*?content=("|\')(.*?)("|\')/i', $str1, $description);
    if (count($description) > 1) {
      return $description[4];   
    } else {
      return getWord($str1);
    }
  }
}

function getWord($html) {
  preg_match('%(<p[^>]*>.*?</p>)%i', $html, $re);
  return get_custom_excerpt($re[1]);
}
```

BTW, parsing HTML with regexp is very fragile, it would be better to use a DOM parser library.